# Gem install/reconfigure throwing exception with JRuby on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

I am getting the following error when I try to run install or anything...

```
jruby -S gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
  at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
  at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609)
  at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
  at org.joda.time.tz.ZoneInfoProvider.readZoneInfoMap(ZoneInfoProvider.java:278)
```

Am I missing some configuration or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was related to the version of JRuby Ubuntu used by default. It was JRuby 1.5x which did not play nice with Ruby 1.9. Installed 1.7.X and now everything is great!